# What do BSONObjects return when using a get method in Java?

Tags: java, mongodb, hadoop, bson

Say I have a Mongo document that looks like this

`{'_id' : NumberLong(123),

'sites' : [{'One',1}, {'Two',2}]

}`

If I have a BSONObject in Java that maps this, say `boop`, would a `BSONObject` or a converted to a Java native object be returned if I return a field value?

For example, `boop.get('sites')` would return a `BSONObject` that represents an array or 
a Java `list<Map<String,Integer>>`?

Edit:

Documentation in the Mongo Java Driver says that the method returns an Object. I am going to assume that it means a converted object, like in a JSON library, but I want to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, then the type of boot.get('sites') will be BasicDBList

```
db.testing.findOne()
{ "_id" : 1, "x" : [ 1, 2, 3 ] }

db.getCollection("testing").findOne().get("x") instanceof BasicDBList : true
```

Comment: do you have a reference to mongodb documentation for this?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I know where to find the API docs for BasicDBList. I wanted to know if it is written somewhere *that* the `.get()` returns a BasicDBList in this case (and other cases, like Strings, ints, doubles etc.)

Comment: The returned value for findOne() is always a BasicDBObject. The function, get() over this BasicDBObject can return any Object, the object that was saved. In the above example, I know, "x" key is storing is a list which is a BasicDBList, when the BSON was changed to a java object.